# python double list comprehension to scala equivalent

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark

Trying to convert some pySpark over to the scala equivalent and I am having issues with the correct syntax for a double list comprehension. The code takes a list of key values and returns a list of values in tuple form that occurred for the same key. Meaning (2, ('user1','user2','user3')) would return (('user1','user2'),('user1','user3'),('user2','user3')).

```
#source rdd
[(2, ['user1', 'user3']), (1, ['user1', 'user2', 'user1']), (3, ['user2', 'user4', 'user4', 'user3'])]

#current list comprehension in pySpark
rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(lambda kv: [(x, y) for x in kv[1] for y in kv[1] if x < y])

//scala attempt to make equivelent is currently throwing errors for syntax issues
val rdd2 = rdd.flatMap((x,y) => for (x <- _(1)) yield x for(y <- _(1)) yield y if x < y)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala supports multiple iterators in a comprehension.

#### Try this

```scala
val rdd2 = rdd.flatMap {
  case (_, v) =>  for {
    x <- v
    y <- v if x < y 
  } yield (x,y)
}
```

#### Notes

The underscore won't work as you did it (twice); either way unwrapping the tuple with Scala's pattern matching is clearer (and closer to Python*). Since you don't use the first tuple item, you *can* use an undescore there to "throw it away".

*FWIW, you *could* do the Python slightly neater:

```python
lambda (_,v): [(x, y) for x in v for y in v if x < y]
```

Comment: this worked without issues, thanks for sorting out the syntax

Comment: Great... please mark the question as answered if it helped!

Answer (score 2):

While the answer provided by [Nick B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604382/nick-b) translates your code directly it makes more sense to use `combinations` here:

```
rdd.values.flatMap(_.toSeq.distinct.sorted.combinations(2))
```